# Example YAML file which shows error in PyYaml module?

Tags: python, yaml

I see `Sublime Pretty Yaml` code uses `pyyaml`,

```
try:
   obj = yaml.load(self.view.substr(selection))
   ....
except:
   ...
   #show error in statusbar
```

so pyyaml may give exception. How to see it, what example file to use to see error in above code?

Comment: Do you want to see the exception in Python program executing in terminal or on Sublime Text status bar?

Comment: Want to see example bad yaml file- which gives err in pyyaml (and Sublime too)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question.  If you're looking for the text of the exception, follow [the example in the pyyaml docs](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#YAMLError).  In other words, continuing with your example:

```
try:
   obj = yaml.load(self.view.substr(selection))
   ....
except yaml.YAMLError, exc:
    if hasattr(exc, 'problem_mark'):
        mark = exc.problem_mark
        errormessage = "Error position: (%s:%s)" % (mark.line+1, mark.column+1)
    else:
        errormessage = "Something else went wrong with ..."
    # do whatever you want with errormessage
```

Comment: I mean other thing; I need example YAML file, which gives error shown in some editor, eg Sublime Text; or in Python app.